# Получить номер строки вызывающей функцию в теле функции

Tags: python

К примеру

```
def f(x):
   line_number=how_get_5_if_call_from_f(2)

f(1)
f(2)
f(3)
```

То есть функция f вызывается несколько раз со строк 4,5,6 (считая номера строк самой функции и пустой строки). Нужно в теле функции, то есть во второй строке, присвоить переменной line_number значение равное номеру строки из которой была вызвана функция.  то есть для f(1) line_number должно быть равно 4 (считая код самой функции и пустую строку)

Comment: Ни_фига_ не понятно. но очень интересно.

Comment: Добавил_объяснения

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С помощью функции [`traceback.extract_stack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_stack) можно получить информацию о стеке вызовов, в том числе из какой строки была вызвана текущая функция:

```
import traceback


def f(x):
    print(traceback.extract_stack())  # Полная информация о стеке вызовов
    print(traceback.extract_stack()[-2].lineno)  # Только номер строки, откуда была вызвана функция


f(1)
f(2)
f(3)
```

Вывод:

```
[<FrameSummary file /home/user/Projects/test.py, line 9 in <module>>, <FrameSummary file /home/user/Projects/test.py, line 5 in f>]
9
[<FrameSummary file /home/user/Projects/test.py, line 10 in <module>>, <FrameSummary file /home/user/Projects/test.py, line 5 in f>]
10
[<FrameSummary file /home/user/Projects/test.py, line 11 in <module>>, <FrameSummary file /home/user/Projects/test.py, line 5 in f>]
11
```

Последний элемент в стеке вызовов соответствует вызову функции `traceback.extract_stack()`, предпоследний (`[-2]`) - вызову функции `f(x)`. Считаем от конца, т.к. вызовов может быть несколько, и первый элемент в стеке будет соответствовать самому внешнему вызову (например, если сначала вызывается функция `main`, а из нее функция `f`, то первый элемент стека будет вызовом функции `main`)

Answer (score 0):

Можно посчитать сколько раз вызывалась:

```
def f(x, count_call):
    if count_call == 2:
       print ('if rows2 --> call in 2 rows')
    print ('call in {0} rows'.format(x))
    return count_call + 1

count_f_call = 0
count_f_call = f(1, count_f_call)
count_f_call = f(2, count_f_call)
count_f_call = f(3, count_f_call)
```

Либо отрабатывать исключение, которое будет говорить в какой строке ошибка:

```
import traceback

def f(x):
    try:
        x / 0
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

f(1)
f(2)
f(3)
```

Comment: нет, это только в примере вызов функции идёт в каждой строке, но на деле между вызовом будет различный код

Comment: traceback возвращает номер строки с исключением, относительно первого варианта проще исспользовать атрибут функции, но он не подходит тк нужны номера строк, а не количества вызовов.